# Crystal report items not displaying when deployed into client pc vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms, crystal-reports

When running the app in my server pc where the database is installed its working and displaying the items in my database but when i install and run it in my client pc its not displaying no errors is showing. im using vb.net 2013 community, wamp mysql as database and sap crystal report version 13.0.12.1494 and i am using odbc im my database connection

here is a screenshot of it working in my server pc

[image: working in my server pc]

here is one from my client pc you can see that my listview is reading and showing the items in the database but when i hit print the crystal report show empty

[image: not wirking in my client pc]

here is my connection string in my app config and moduleconnection

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
  </startup>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySqlConnectionString" connectionString="SERVER=192.168.1.2;DATABASE=payparkingsystem;UID=connect;PASSWORD=password;" />
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

moduleconnection.vb.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
Imports System.Configuration
Module ModuleConnection

    Public connString1 As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MySqlConnectionString").ToString()
    Public conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(connString1)
    Public sql As String = ""

    Public Function ExecuteQuery(ByVal query As String) As DataTable
        Dim sqlDT As New DataTable
        Try
            Dim sqlCon As New MySqlConnection(connString1)
            Dim sqlDA As New MySqlDataAdapter(query, sqlCon)
            Dim sqlCB As New MySqlCommandBuilder(sqlDA)
            sqlDA.Fill(sqlDT)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        Return sqlDT
    End Function
End Module
```

here is my print code

```
Public Sub PrintEmployeeAccountsLogsSearch()
        Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument
        cryRpt.Load("C:\Reports\CrystalReportPrintEmployeeAccountsLogsSearch.vb.rpt")
        Dim crParameterFieldDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions
        Dim crParameterFieldDefinition As ParameterFieldDefinition
        Dim crParameterValues As New ParameterValues
        Dim crParameterDiscreteValue As New ParameterDiscreteValue
        crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = print
        crParameterFieldDefinitions = cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
        crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("My Parameter")
        crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues
        crParameterValues.Clear()
        crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)
        crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)
        FormPrintEmployeeAccountsLogsSearch.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
        FormPrintEmployeeAccountsLogsSearch.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
        cryRpt.PrintToPrinter(1, True, 0, 0)
    End Sub
```

here is a screenshot of my database

[image]

I hope that someone can help me fix my error any help would be appreciated Thank you in advance and more power guys!

Answer (score 0):

Dou you connect the database from your client?

Comment: I assume that it is connected because my listview is showing the items in my database and my log in is working too.

Comment: I'm seeing something on your code for printing the report, you are calling the ExecuteQuery wich is meant to return the datasource for your report, I assume that you are accessing the database through the report, is that right?

Comment: I only use the executequery in manipulating items in the table like adding, editing or deleting items in my database. The items that will be shown in my crystal reports comes from the table. @guto condela

Comment: Can you share with me your  crystal report file?

Comment: [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15zT9LUhapc5sdQMZdYxaXyQ7AxNEPBZR) is the .rpt file